# SSO blocking Frontdoor URL logins

Tags: single-sign-on, accesstoken, frontdoor.jsp

I'm using the frontdoor URL method to login to multiple orgs. Some have SSO and some don't. The setup works fine for all orgs.

Except for one org... This org has SSO enabled and using the frontdoor login method redirects to the SSO login page instead of actually logging in.  I've turned off SSO temporary and the frontdoor URL started working fine. I'm struggling to figure out why this method works for countless of orgs with SSO but not this one org.

The SSO configuration doesn't look any different than others on the Salesforce side, and I'm able to successfully get an access token without errors.

It's also worth mentioning that the access token is obtained via a connected app.

Here's how I'm constructing the frontdoor URL:

```
public static String requestFrontDoorURL(AccessTokenResponse response) {
    if(String.isBlank(response.access_token)) {
        throw new HandledException(response.error + ' - ' + response.error_description);
    }
    return response.instance_url + '/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(response.access_token, 'UTF-8');
}

public class AccessTokenResponse {
    public String access_token;
    public String instance_url;
    public String id;
    public String token_type;
    public String issued_at;
    public String signature;
    public String error;
    public String error_description;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the construction of the frontdoor URL so we can make sure it is being put together correctly?

Comment: @BryanAnderson I've added the code to the question.

Comment: is `AccessTokenResponse` a custom Apex type you developed? If so can you include the class for that as well

Comment: @BryanAnderson It's basically whatever the API returns when access token is requested. All values seem to be populated correctly and no errors. I added the class to the question as well.

Comment: Looks like you might have already ensured that the connected app scope is either `web` or `full`. Have you tried reconfiguring the connected app just in case? i.e., change the scope, save it and reset it back to required scope value. Its a long shot, but give it a try.